# How to count json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

How can i count the object of my request?

I am using ajax and  requesting json data to this url `pbxApi+"/conference/participants/"+circle+"/"+data.conference+"/"+data.uniqueid+'?jsonp=response';` and i want to count the object of the response .

This is my code

```
 var uri = pbxApi+"/conference/participants/"+circle+"/"+data.conference+"/"+data.uniqueid+'?jsonp=response';
        getJsonData(uri, function(res){
            console.log(res.length);
});
```

This is my functiion:

```
  var getJsonData = function(uri,callback){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: uri,
      jsonpCallback: 'response',
      cache: false,
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(json){
        callback(json);
      }
    });
  }
```

This is my response

```
response({"_id":"561713a78693609968e3bbdd","event":"ConfbridgeJoin","channel":"SIP/192.168.236.15-00000024","uniqueid":"1444352918.94","conference":"0090000293","calleridnum":"0090000288","calleridname":"0090000288","__v":0,"status":false,"sipSetting":{"accountcode":"0302130000","accountcode_naisen":"201","extentype":0,"extenrealname":"UID1","name":"0090000288","secret":"Myojyo42_f","username":"0090000288","context":"innercall_xdigit","gid":101,"cid":"0090000018"}})
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "count the object"?

Comment: It is very dificult to answer without the 'structure' of `json` in the response

Comment: i added my response @Anonymous0day

Comment: It's still unclear what "count the object" means. An object is a single thing. So it's "1".

Comment: I assume you mean "count the properties", which is a duplicate. If not, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Object.keys(jsonArray).length;
```

to get the number of items in your JSON object.

Also refer [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> Object.keys() returns an array whose elements are strings
>   corresponding to the enumerable properties found directly upon object.
>   The ordering of the properties is the same as that given by looping
>   over the properties of the object manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
success: function(json){
    console.log('Object keys length: ' + Object.keys(json).length)
    callback(json);
}
```

For example `{a:1, b:2, c:'Batman'}` gives `3` as an answer

Answer (score 0):

One Solution

```js
 var uri = pbxApi+"/conference/participants/"+circle+"/"+data.conference+"/"+data.uniqueid+'?jsonp=response';

var getJsonData = function(uri,callback){
    return $.ajax({ // <----- note the return !
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: uri,
      jsonpCallback: 'response',
      cache: false,
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(json){
        if(callback) callback(json);
      }
    });
  }

getJsonData(uri, function(res){
  console.log( Objec.keys(res).length) );
});

// with the return you will be able to do :
getJsonData(uri)
  .done( function(res){
    console.log( Objec.keys(res).length) );
  })
  .error(function( err ){
     console.log('an error ?? what is it possible ?');  
  });
```

Comment: What's so important about the `return`? You are not even making use of it.

Comment: To chain  without callback, i will update my answer to understand

Comment: That doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question though.

Comment: @FelixKling you right ! it is a plus !  :-)